# Is there a way to apply a boolean modifier to a metaball?

Tags: modifiers, animation-nodes, meta-objects

Is this possible with Animation Nodes?

If not, how do you convert a metaball to a mesh that can then have modifiers applied, and by extension can you do this simultaneously for multiple frames of an animation so you don't have to do it manually for each frame.